# Make a SPA crawlable

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have an SPA. What happens is that when user click any button or link it retrieves new contents from server but it does not update the url. Now my task is that I have to make it crawlable for search engines such as google. I heard that Phantomjs could be used to get all of the html from website and make it crawable that way somehow. But I am not sure about this method. I want to know how can I use this method to make website crawlable via phantomjs. Any help about this?

Comment: See here: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution would be to pre-render the pages with phantom on the server, and when a robot requests a page, the server returns a static html.
Check this [link](http://lawsonry.com/2014/05/diy-angularjs-seo-with-phantomjs-the-easy-way/) to see it in detail,

```
phantomjs --disk-cache=no angular-seo-server.js 9090 http://127.0.0.1:9000
```

> This will start a phantomJS server with no disk caching on port 9090. It’s
>   important to note that PhantomJS’s port needs to be different from the
>   port that your application runs on.